# BindingExpression path error itemtemplate

Tags: binding, binding-expressions

I am using following ItemTemplate in a TabControl to set the content of the tab item and the foreground color of the tab item. Both properties are available in the same ViewModel class:

```
       <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter 
                        Content="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        TextElement.Foreground="{Binding Path=Color, Converter={converter:ColorToBrushConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

As for the 'Name' property everything works as expected. When the property is modified the name on the tab item changes.
But for the 'Color' property this does not work. I keep getting

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Color' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=2145491359)'. BindingExpression:Path=Color; DataItem='String' (HashCode=2145491359); target element is 'ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'Foreground' (type 'Brush')

When setting the TextElement.Foreground to a constant color, e.g. "white", it works.

What's wrong with my binding?